# WPF WebBrowser telling when user has navigated with a click of a button

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control that is pointed at a website not owned by me. It is a rather slow server and I want to display the wait cursor (mouse pointer) while waiting for page loading. If the navigation is instantiated with the Navigate() method, there is no problem, Navigating and Load_Completed events inform me what is happening. However, if the user navigates by clicking a button, the Navigating event does not "fire". Is there any event (or combination of events/properties) that can be used to this purpose?